# Babel doesn't compile all the files

Tags: typescript, babeljs

I'm running a new project with Babel 7 + Typescript. I'm learning Typescript and it was quite a challenge to combine the two of them. I managed to do it, but I still have one issue.

When I compile my project, all .ts files from `./src/` are converted to .js files in `./dist/`. All dotfiles are ignored, which is expected. However, all files which don't have the .ts extension in `./src/` are also ignored.

Here are some of the many commands that I've tried:

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    // build1 compiles only the .js files
    "build1": "babel src --out-dir dist",

    // build2 compiles only the .ts files
    "build2": "babel src --out-dir dist --extensions \".ts\"",

    //build 3 compiles only the .ts files
    "build3": "babel src --out-dir dist --extensions \".ts, .js\"",

    //build 4 compiles only the .js files
    "build4": "babel src --out-dir dist --extensions \".js, .ts\""
},
```

Here is my babel config file

```
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/typescript",
  ],
  plugins: [
    "transform-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread"
  ],
};
```

Any idea?

Many thanks!

**Update:** Removing the space from the --extension argument works, but now I have a side effect which I didn't observe before. When running the command `"babel src --out-dir dist --extensions \".ts,.js,.json\""`, I see an issue with the .json files which are also converted to .js.
I would like babel to transform .ts to .js, compile the .js files and just copy any other file as is.

Comment: A quick guess: is the space in the `--extensions` argument being treated as part of the extension and preventing a match?  Try removing it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is good information:) But unfortunately I now observe that my files are all converted to .js, even the .json for example (see my update above).

Answer (score 11):

I finally found the solution. I had to add the --copy-files argument to the command.

> babel src --out-dir dist --extensions \".ts,.js\" --copy-files

`--extensions \".ts,.js\"` tells babel to compile all .ts and .js files.

`--copy-files` tells babel to copy all the other files.